# Checking if a static block is enabled/disabled on a multi-store site

Tags: magento-1.9, php, template, static-block, performance

I've recently found two methods for checking if a static block is enabled on a multi-store site:

#### getIsActive() method

```
<?php
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    $block = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->setStoreId($storeId)->load('footer_promo_as_seen');
    $blockIsActive = $block->getIsActive();
?>

<?php if($blockIsActive): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('footer_promo_as_seen')->toHtml(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

#### !empty method

```
<?php $asSeenHtml = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('footer_promo_as_seen')->toHtml(); ?>

<?php if (!empty($asSeenHtml)): ?>
        <?php echo $asSeenHtml; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

My question is, **which one negatively affects performance the most?**. I suspect the `getIsActive()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, the `getIsActive()` method would theoretically be the less performant method; however, the difference between the two is negligible.

The reason is that the first is slower is because it is duplicating existing code:

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    $blockId = $this->getBlockId();
    $html = '';
    if ($blockId) {
        $block = Mage::getModel('cms/block')
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->load($blockId);
        if ($block->getIsActive()) {
            /* @var $helper Mage_Cms_Helper_Data */
            $helper = Mage::helper('cms');
            $processor = $helper->getBlockTemplateProcessor();
            $html = $processor->filter($block->getContent());
            $this->addModelTags($block);
        }
    }
    return $html;
}
```

That is the `_toHtml` method from the class `Mage_Cms_Block_Block`. As you probably know, this method is called internally to render a block. Therefore, in the first example, when the `toHtml()` method is called, this method will be called and it will recheck the status.

If you have any questions, please let me know!

Comment: Good point! So they also have the same outcome? If so I think the `!empty` method is the winner as it saves me having to get store IDs to. Thank you

Comment: Yes, exactly. Also, since they're using `getModel()`, it keeps you from having to reload the same entity twice...

Answer (score 2):

I would like to point out two things here.

```
<?php if($blockIsActive): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('footer_promo_as_seen')->toHtml(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is completely has to avoid. Instead, you can use below code.

```
<?php if($blockIsActive): ?>
    <?php echo $block->toHtml(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This will avoid further model loading. Still the above example will instantiate `cms/block` model two times which @tjons explained in his answer.

**My second point is**, this scenario is completely wrong. You dont need to check whether a `cms/block` is active or not in your code. This is because Magento already do that for you and it will give you an empty string if it is not active. Please see `_toHtml()` method.

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    $blockId = $this->getBlockId();
    $html = '';
    if ($blockId) {
        $block = Mage::getModel('cms/block')
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->load($blockId);
        if ($block->getIsActive()) {
            /* @var $helper Mage_Cms_Helper_Data */
            $helper = Mage::helper('cms');
            $processor = $helper->getBlockTemplateProcessor();
            $html = $processor->filter($block->getContent());
            $this->addModelTags($block);
        }
    }
    return $html;
}
```

So basically, you just need to do this :

```
<?php 
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')
        ->setBlockId('footer_promo_as_seen')
        ->toHtml(); 
?>
```

This will render `cms/block` content if it is active or any empty string (`''`) if it is not active.

Comment: My problem is inside the template file there is some markup around the CMS block that should not be rendered if the static block is disabled. I know it could be added to the static block in most cases but I'm this is more theoretical for me than an actual piece of work.